# BeautifulSoup4 table

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I've found several articles on how to do this but i'm not having luck with any of them for bs4. Can anyone help me figure out how to pull out the `filename.doc` from this table with bs4? I've tried a million things and i'm not having much luck and cant find the answer in the documentation. **There are additional tables in the html i'm scraping that have `<table class="layout">`**

table that i'm trying to parse:

```
<table class="layout">
  <tbody>
    <tr>.(truncating td's).</tr>
    <tr>.(truncating td's).</tr>
    <tr>.(truncating td's).</tr>
    <tr>.(truncating td's).</tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="color:999999;"></td>
      <td>filename.doc</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

here is the py code i am attempting.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint 
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("/home/myuser/message_tracking.html"), "html.parser")

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'layout'})
print table
table_body = table.findAll('tr')
print table_body
```

since this table doesn't have many unique attributes that I can use, how do i pull out 'filename.doc' from this html? thank you all in advance for taking time to help!

Comment: Can't you match `<td style="color:999999;">` and then find the next `td` ?

Comment: that `<td style="color:999999;">` is in the other tr's that i truncated from the example

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to the criteria for the filename you're trying to extract. Do you want a list of the text from the second column of each row?

Comment: Is this is always the last `td` in this table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about we just find the element that *ends with `.doc`*. Clean and readable:

```
>>> import re
...
>>> soup.find(text=re.compile(r"\.doc$"))
u'filename.doc'
>>> soup.find("td", text=re.compile(r"\.doc$")).get_text()
u'filename.doc'
>>> soup.find(text=lambda text: text and text.endswith("doc"))
u'filename.doc'
>>> soup.find("td", text=lambda text: text and text.endswith("doc")).get_text()
u'filename.doc'
```

`\` escapes the dot, `$` - is the end of the string.

You can generalize the problem to handle multiple extensions. For instance, you may define a tuple of extensions and pass to `endswith()`:

```
>>> EXTENSIONS = ('doc', 'docx')
>>> soup.find("td", text=lambda text: text and text.endswith(EXTENSIONS)).get_text()
u'filename.doc'
```

Or, you can improve the regular expression to expect a dot be followed by 3 or more lower case letters at the end of the string:

```
>>> soup.find("td", text=re.compile(r"\.[a-z]{3,}$")).get_text()
u'filename.doc'
```

---

Also, if this is *always the last `td` element* in the table, you can do:

```
>>> table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'layout'})
>>> table.find_all("td")[-1].get_text()
u'filename.doc'
```

Comment: only issue is the filename may not always be .doc.

Comment: @dobbs not a problem at all. You can generalize the expression: `\.[a-z]{3,}$"` will match a dot followed by 3 or more lower-case characters at the end of the string.

Comment: @dobbs updated the answer with some more information and options.

Comment: The OP did specify that there might be other tables with the same class.

Comment: @pydsigner good point, the picture is still not big enough to be sure these options would work as is, they will probably need adjustments. For now, these are just advices and pointers that work on the provided html sample. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well well well... from what I see, there is not many option. So here is my tries:

1. Match the n'th element (if the order does not change)

   ```
   soup.findAll('td')[42]
   ```
2. Match for the one `td` that ends with a `.doc`

   ```
   soup.find('td', text=lambda text: text.endswith('.doc'))
   ```

Comment: that may work. i will update with what just worked for me, though i dont know if it will always work in every situation.

Comment: @dobbs don't go with `soup.findAll('td')[42]` - it is too fragile to last long, bad locator.

Comment: It only depends of the html he is parsing. No need to put the big warning here.

Comment: @Cyrbil well, nothing personal, just trying to help using my experience with html parsing. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
string = '''
<table class="layout">
  <tbody>
    <tr>.(truncating td's).</tr>
    <tr>.(truncating td's).</tr>
    <tr>.(truncating td's).</tr>
    <tr>.(truncating td's).</tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="color:999999;"></td>
      <td>filename.doc</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
'''


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(string,"html.parser")
ans = [tddata.get_text() for tabledata in soup.find_all('table',{'class':'layout'}) for tddata in tabledata.find_all('td')]

print(ans[1])
```

Here ans is the list of text available in each `td` tag of `table class ="layout"`

To remove empty strings you can do something like this:

```
finalans = [each for each in ans if not(each == '')]
```

Comment: Do you mean `tr` or `td`? Your code gets the text from the `td`s but refers to it as `trdata`.

Comment: Your empty string remover loop is expensive and buggy. Better by far to use another list comprehension.